# Change file name with photoshop action

Tags: html, css, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have 100 PNG sliced images for iPhone retina with 326 dpi

like.. login@2x.png, textfield@2x.png etc...

now I want to same images for normal view in 163 dpi, we can easily change 100 files resolutions with Photoshop action in a single click, but is there any way that we can also change file name with action ?

like from login@2x.png to login.png

Comment: I don't think that the "@" character should be used in file names should it? http://www.exadox.com/en/articles/file-naming-convention-ten-rules-best-practice

Comment: @BillyMoat "@2x" in the image name is required by Apple; debating the merits of using "@" in an iOS image name is pointless, and doesn't really address the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you're recording the action.

Don't "Save" the original. Instead, do "Save As" (ctrl+shift+S) and save it to a new directory. Then close the original file without saving!

When you run your action, all the files will save into the new directory.

Now you can use the batch rename tool in photoshop to rename your files, but if you want a real beefy renaming utility, try Bulk Rename Utility (freeware)

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

It can do just about any bulk renaming action you can think of, plus some.

Answer (score 1):

I think With photoshop you cant do it (not sure)
But I always use http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/renamers/Batch_Rename_Picture_Files_Tools_Tips.htm

Some of these tools